# Azure Devops custom grid field project template

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, azure-devops-extensions

I'm looking for an example to create some kind of Grid in azure devops Work Item

I would like to create a custom control to put a grid and define fields in that grid, this way I could create some json information in a form, as an array of data to be used in my process

for example, list the fields in a form, or list the steps in a program.

Is there a tutorial or a project template on c# or typescript to implement custom fields in azure devops work itens?